# Write each of the following functions as a composition of functions chosen from $f$, $g$, and $h$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $f(x)=|x|$, $g(x)=x-7$, and $h(x)=x^2$.
>
> 1. $A(x)=x^2-7$
> 2. $B(x)=x^2-14x+49$
> 3. $C(x)= |x-7|$
> 4. $D(x)=(x^2-7)^2$

For number one I tried using $(fog)(x)= f(g(x))$ but I got the answer as being the absolute value of $x-7$ which is wrong. Please help.
I understand how it works now. Thank you very much everyone!

Comment: Do you just need number 1, or any of the others?

Comment: I do not understand how to do one. I need all the answers but if you show me how to do one maybe I will be able to do the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A(x)=g \circ h(x)$ since $g \circ h(x)=g (h(x))=g(x^2)=x^2-7$

$B(x)=h(g(x))$ since $h (g(x))=h((x-7))=(x-7)^2=x^2-14x+49$

Try to complete the other two,

Hint for the last one, you have to make two compositions.

Answer (score 1):

$A(x)=(g\circ h)(x)$ as $g(x^{2})=x^{2}-7$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $g(x^2)$, or am I missing something?

Comment: Ouch Ouch! I messed the order up, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

1. $A = g\circ h$ since $g(h(x)) = h(x)-7 = x^2-7$
2. $B = h\circ g$ since $h(g(x)) = (x-7)^2 = x^2-2\cdot 7x + 49$
3. $C = f\circ g$ since $f(g(x)) = \lvert g(x)\rvert = \lvert x-7\rvert$
4. $D = h\circ g\circ h$ since $h(g(h(x))) = \left(g(x^2)\right)^2 = (x^2-7)^2$